# Is it typical for a person to feel discomfort while standing back up straight after a comfortable dead-lift set is completed?

Tags: deadlifts, back-pain, glutes

After I complete some dead lifts, and lower the weight back to the ground and begin to stand back up straight *un-weighted*, I feel an uncomfortable stiffness **(*EDIT*)<s>in my lower back</s> at the top of my buttocks directly behind my hip bones on both sides, but not the center: ie. definitely not spinal pain.**

Why would I feel this only after I stand back up straight from the low position *without* weight, but not with weight?  That doesn't seem to make sense.

In other words, if I made the same motion with a 200lb dead-lift load for another rep (comfortably), I would not feel this same disconcerting sensation while loaded, but once I stand back up after the set is done, I feel like I am doing the "old, hunched over, man, 'ow, my back'", motion trying to stand back up straight unloaded.

It is not a sharp *pain*, but more of an unsettling sensation, and it is only experienced while I am in transit from being bent over to standing straight up again, and once I am straightened out vertically, the sensation quickly goes away.

Should I be concerned about this, or is this commonly accepted as a normal experience?

Comment: That's a good question, and I know exactly what you're referring to. I can't say I have the definitive answer (so I'm making a comment instead), but I've always taken for granted that you're just feeling a compression of your spine as a result of loading a lot of weight on your shoulders, which presses downward. One thing that helps me is to do a deadhang for a few seconds after each set. I do the same after sets of squats for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have determined what this sensation is.  It is definitely declining as I continue to train, even with more weight, and was likely a result of me being new to this type of lift.

In the same way that runners get pain in the connective tissues of their leg muscles, known as 'shin splints', I was getting this in my glutes' tendons from the tensions I was not used to.

This is probably normal for beginners, but even at higher weights, not experienced by intermediate lifters.

Answer (score 2):

While You're using the muscles and they're loaded the same neural pathways responsible for sensing discomfort are used to stimulate the muscles (or so I've read in Becoming Supple Leopard by Kelly Starret).

I think it also depends on the ratio of different fiber types that were used in the movement.

> Research has suggested that postural and phasic
>   muscles respond differently to stress, with postural
>   muscles responding by shortening, but phasic muscles
>   becoming inhibited neurologically and thence weakening. This behaviour will have structural outcomes in
>   the longer term.

(Smith J. 2005, The Muscular System. Structural Bodywork)

I strongly suggest checking this paper.